# remover texto dentro da small sem altrar a tag "a" com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código, e gostaria de remover apenas o texto ' Opções de configuração:' sem  alterar a tag "a" com jquery, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
<small>

Opções de configuração: 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="teste" class="hiperlink" alt="">Alterar
</a>

</small>
```

Comment: Poste o código, que ai podemo ajudar

Comment: desculpe, sou novo por aqui
segue https://jsfiddle.net/82jnnsvu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar texto dentro de elementos com `nodeType == 3`:

```js
$('small').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small>

Opções de configuração: 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="teste" class="hiperlink" alt="">Alterar
</a>

</small>
```

Comment: Gostei da sua solução +1

Answer (score 1):

Criei um botão que ao ser clicado armazenará o `link` em uma variável (selecionando por sua classe *hiperlink*) em seguida limpará o conteúdo da tag `<small>` com o método [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) e posteriormente acrescentará a seu conteúdo a variável `link` através do método [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```js
$("#Remover").on("click", function(){
  var link = $(".hiperlink");
  $("small").empty().append(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<small>
  Opções de configuração: 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="teste" class="hiperlink" alt="">
    Alterar
  </a>
</small>

<div>
  <button id="Remover">
    Clique para remover o texto
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode alterar o html dessa forma

```js
$("#tag-small").html($("#tag-small a"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small id="tag-small">

Opções de configuração: 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="teste" class="hiperlink" alt="">Alterar
</a>

</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução possível é mudares o teu `html` para

```js
$("small > span").text("");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<small>
    
  <span>Opções de configuração:</span> 

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="teste" class="hiperlink" alt="">
    Alterar
  </a>

</small>
```